# How to plot in matlab using the besselh function with a given range of k (reduced frequency)?

Tags: matlab, plot, bessel-functions

I am using a Matlab function called besselh which gives an exact solution to Theoderon's lift deficiency function for a two-dimensional airfoil executing a simple harmonic motion in incompressible flow with a given range of k.

I am trying to plot the real part of this function with the given range of k. I feel I am missing something really simple in my code. Perhaps, I might be using the for loop wrong by including the "plot" function within the loop?

```
for k=10^-10:0.2:1.5 %range of k
H=(besselh(1,2,k))/(besselh(1,2,k)+i*besselh(0,2,k)) %Bessel function
plot(k,real(H))
%plot(k,imag(H))
end
```

Below is a picture of how the plot should look like (solid line).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

[image: This is how the plot should look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to plot each point individually. Just calculate the function across the whole range for `k` and then plot:

```
k = 10^-10:0.2:1.5; %range of k
% notice the ./ means element-wise vector division
H = (besselh(1,2,k)) ./ (besselh(1,2,k) + i * besselh(0,2,k)); %Bessel function
plot(k,real(H))
```

Comment: That works! I knew it was something simple. I actually had the same exact code you just posted but I missed the period before the division sign "./" which was just giving me one value to plot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jesus glad I could help.

Comment: @StaticBeagle Thank you!